# How to use Intellij's jre in ubuntu

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij to write code in Java, if I run my software inside Intellij my software works but, if I create a jar file and I try to start it from my terminal it says that the jre version is too old.
My question is, if the JDK includes also the jre and my software works in Intellij, why it doesn't from the Ubuntu's terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intelij is poiting to a different java version than the one configured in your terminal path.

If you want to keep booth  version the same you can look in Intelij Settings to find out which version it is using, then replace the /usr/bin/java link in your terminal to point to the same java binary.

Or, simply folow these step to just update your teminal version: [install-java-ubuntu](https://thishosting.rocks/install-java-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about IntelliJ but why not just update the system JRE so it is the same as or more recent than the version that IntelliJ uses?